# multiple php if statements in one ternary operator

Tags: php, if-statement

I have multiple if statements for checking value of four Checkboxes. but i see my code not good and contains duplicate code in every if statement.

I know use ternary operator for one if statement condition. But i want put below my code in one ternary operator. How can i do this?

**INFO:** ternary operator standard use `condition ? action_if_true: action_if_false;`

```
if (!empty($item->divideto_2)) {
    $col = 6;
    $divide_to = 12 / $col;
}
if (!empty($item->divideto_3)) {
    $col = 4;
    $divide_to = 12 / $col;
}
if (!empty($item->divideto_4)) {
    $col = 3;
    $divide_to = 12 / $col;
}
if (!empty($item->divideto_6)) {
    $col = 2;
    $divide_to = 12 / $col;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a ternary operator to put all of this into one line. You'd be stringing multiple ternaries and it would get too complicated. Instead, use else if to reduce the number of checks.

Comment: In addition to nested ternary statments being confusing, unreadable, and [above all] *unmaintainable*; nested ternaries would need to replaced nested if/else statements, which yours are not.

Comment: if you dont like `if`, you can try `switch` :D

Comment: `switch` is for a single variable that can assume a list of well known values. It doesn't fit OP needs.

Comment: thanks for the head up, still learning programming :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$col = 0;
$divide_to = 12 / (( ! empty($item->divideto_2)) 
                    ? ($col = 6)
                    : ( ! empty($item->divideto_3))
                        ? ($col = 4)
                        : ( ! empty($item->divideto_4))
                            ? ($col = 3)
                            : ( ! empty($item->divideto_6))
                                ? ($col = 2)
                                : $col);
```

But, for better visualization, use another form.